Cómo hago para que no esté oculto el pie de página
Estoy haciendo una pagina web que está compuesta en este orden:
1ro) Menú desplegable
2do) Encabezado (El título de la página)
3ro) El subtítulo
4to) La nota importante
5to) La barra de búsqueda
6to) El php que llama imágenes que están subidas en AWS S3 al cuerpo de mi página web
7mo) El pie de página
El problema que tengo es que el php en el centro de todo mi html hace que no aparezca el pie de página. Cuando saco el php sí aparece, pero cuando lo pongo no.
El código es más o menos así:
php
JavaScrip
Pie de página

Cómo hago para que no suceda eso y acepte el php ahí? Cabe decir que el php empieza con session start.

Hola, si yo te digo que tienes que hacer que se muestre, aceptarias esto como una respuesta?

Dale botón derecho y "ver código fuente", posiblemente haya etiquetas mal cerradas. Me gusta hacer esto con Firefox, que si marca en rojo etiquetas que no tienen su contraparte. Si no sale nada raro, entonces mira en las herramientas de desarrollador (Inspeccionar) qué componente es el que se hace que el pie no salga.

Hola Christopher, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y agregues en ella el código al que haces referencia, mostrando lo que has intentado, asi no solo recibirás ayuda, sino que evitarás recibir votos negativos y/o el cierre de la misma
